# Durable functions timeout

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm using a durable function to orchestrate a long running task.

THis task is expected to have a duration of 2-3hrs, so I've set the function timeout in *host.json* as below:

```
"functionTimeout": "05:00:00"
```

This removes the timeout being triggered after the 30 min default. Howver after 1 hour of execution, I now get the below result from the function execution (result from the statusQueryGetUri endpoint):

> "output": {
> "statusCode": 400,
> "headers": {},
> "content": "There was a error: \r\n[System.NotSupportedException]\r\n[Specified method is not supported.]\r\n"
> }

What causes this to be triggered? Applications insights does not record this exception, which makes me suspect this is internal to Azure Functions. The task is expected to run for longer than 1 hour.